# XCUITest - Tap on Navigation title when it is a button

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

Hi we change the title of the nav bar to a button so we can show the user a new set of information when tapped. This however makes life difficult for UI testing with XCUITest. We change the title to a button programmatically and I have set the accessbilitylabel and still can't access the button.

I have changed the accessibility label. 
Search by text (even though it is dynamic pending user selection)
Used the UI Accessibility inspector- the one with the iOS 9 < sims and the new one with Xcode 8.
Search by otherElements
I did the record and tapped the button but it gave me nonsense and when i used nonsense it hits another spot of the view

Any help would be appreciated.